# cakephp displays 1 with every flash message

Tags: session, cakephp, message

I'm using cakephp and whenever there comes a session based flash message, there comes "1" after every error/success message, why?

It is related with "echo" before this flashmessage, so any idea, which file to make correction for it? We're using cakephp 1.2 version - FYI

Earliest reply would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the echo in front of your flash call `$session->flash();`  in `default.ctp`, that should do it

Comment: its like <?php $session->flash(); ?> no echo there, and still it displays "1"... any idea?

Comment: hmm, remove that bit and see if it still shows up. If it does, then you're editing the wrong file

Comment: yes u're right, i remove that flash code and still the flash message appears with 1, i have also tried to edit into default cake's view template, still doesn't help.

Comment: Don't edit anything inside the library. Make sure you're editing the correct template. Do you have it inside views/layout ?

Comment: yes, i have put things back into library, as it was, yes i am editing into app/views/layout/default.ctp file.. but no difference yet..

Comment: Then it must be an issue when you put the message into the session. Check your `setFlash()` call.

Comment: well, not sure about but just for your ref `$this->Session->setFlash('some flash message');` it is the way, we're using it into controllers

Comment: hmm, weird. something in your view or layout is getting in the way. maybe a partial. You might want to do a project wide text search for `$session->flash(` to see where it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but you haven't done some thing like this

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__( $this->FileHandler->errorMessage . true),'flash_error')
```

In the INCORRECT example above the __() internationalizations method should take two arguments. You haven't accidentally concatenated boolean true on the end?